# null check operator used in a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

hello guys i wrote this program in flutter to make map with marker in place where I found it don't make errors in the analyzer but when i open it in emulator it make a red screen has this  problem null check operator used in a null value what should i do i confused I modified this code many times it said before
field cl has not been  initialized

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

 void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
      home: const MapSample(),
    );
  }
}


class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapSample({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  double posla = 0.0;
  double poslo = 0.0;
  String country = "0";
  String admin = "0";
   String local = "0";
   String sublocal = "0";
   String post = "0";
   String street = "0";

  static Position? cl;
  late var lat;
  late var long;
  late CameraPosition _kGooglePlex;
  Future getper() async {
    bool services;
   LocationPermission per = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    services = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
   if (per == LocationPermission.denied) {
      per = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (per == LocationPermission.always) {}
    }

    print("=========================");
    print(per);
     print("===========================");
     return per;
   }

   Future<Position?> getLatAndLong() async {
    cl = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition().then((value) => value);
    lat = cl?.latitude;
    long = cl?.longitude;
    _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(lat, long), zoom: 12.4746, tilt: 45, bearing: 45);
     setState(() {});
    return cl;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getper();
    getLatAndLong();
    super.initState();
 }

  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();
  late GoogleMapController gmc;
  Set<Marker> mymarker = {
    Marker(
       markerId: MarkerId("1"), position: LatLng(cl!.latitude, cl!.longitude))
  };
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
       _kGooglePlex == null
           ? CircularProgressIndicator()
           : Container(
              child: GoogleMap(
                markers: mymarker,
                 mapType: MapType.hybrid,
                initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  gmc = controller;
                },
              ),
              height: 150,
              width: 500,
            ),
      Text('$posla'),
      Text('$poslo'),
      Text('$country'),
      Text('$admin'),
      Text('$local'),
      Text('$sublocal'),
      Text('$post'),
      Text('$street'),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            cl = await getLatAndLong();
            print("lat ${cl!.latitude}");
            print("Long ${cl!.longitude}");
            List<Placemark> placemarks =
                 await placemarkFromCoordinates(cl!.latitude, cl!.longitude);

            setState(() {
              posla = cl!.latitude;
              poslo = cl!.longitude;
              country = placemarks[0].country!;
              admin = placemarks[0].administrativeArea!;
              local = placemarks[0].locality!;
              sublocal = placemarks[0].subLocality!;
              post = placemarks[0].postalCode!;
              street = placemarks[0].street!;
            });
          },
           child: Text("إظهر الاحداثيات")),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
           LatLng latLng = LatLng(31.042639, 29.964639);
            //   gmc.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(latLng));
            gmc.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                 CameraPosition(target: latLng, zoom: 10)));
          },
           child: Text("gotoalex"))
    ]));
  }
}`
```

//31.042639   29.964639

```
I tried solve this problem but it make errors
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: null check operator used in a null value

Comment: So somewhere you used a null check operator on a null value.  You should find out why that's null, and why you promised it would not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i can see only one variable `cl` as nullable so i guess it may causing the error,
so try replacing it's declaration `static Position? cl;` with the below code:

```
  Position cl = Position(
      longitude: 0,
      latitude: 0,
      timestamp: DateTime.now(),
      accuracy: 0,
      altitude: 0,
      heading: 0,
      speed: 0,
      speedAccuracy: 0);
```

here we are giving it a initial value, it can be changed on your button click as your doing now.